Where to download C++ WinApi libraries if there is only `.h` file in compiler folder?
I've recently installed mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain, acting according to this instruction. I thought that everything is fine until met undefined reference error with shellscalingapi. The weird moment here is that I've found the header (shellscalingapi.h), but there is no the library itself anywhere in C:\msys64\ucrt64 (tried recursive search).
This code compiles...
#include <shellscalingapi.h>

int main(){
    SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE);
    return 0;
}

But on linking stage it says:
"undefined reference to `SetProcessDpiAwareness'"
Can anyone tell how to download missing libraries?

Open docs for the function, scroll to bottom, find "Library", link to it. You might need to install WindowsSDK first.

@Osyotr Wouldn't the presence of the header indicate that the library is installed somewhere?

Just a wild guess, but: Not sure how you compile but on the command line it may be sufficient to say "-lShcore" when you call gcc to build the executable. Since it is a Microsoft library it may not be in the msys folder (but the gcc installation is configured to search the Windows folders for libraries).

shellscalingapi.h is not part of the standard library. It is part of the Win32 API.

Indeed, I find the library in /c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64/shcore.lib and
/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x86/shcore.lib, for 32 and 64 bit applications, respectively. Perhaps you need to link to them using the full path, or set LIBRARY_PATH for gcc.

You don't need to install anything extra to use WinAPI.
Google the specific function you have problem with, find the manual.
Notice Library: Shcore.lib. This means you need to add -lshcore to the linker flags. This will link libshcore.a that comes with your compiler.

How can I add any static lib in a folder recursively (I mean in that folder, and all it's subfolders, and it's subfolders' subfolders, etc)?

@TechoftheAbsence Not sure, and this is probably not the best idea. Just creates more work for the linker that now needs to remove unnecessary libraries.

Unfortunately, the reference is still considered undefined.

@TechoftheAbsence Show your compiler command. What's your code, same as you have in the question?

g++ -c -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" src\main\java\com\azcomplex\com_azcomplex_CHandler.cpp 


here is my command. Note, I've also tried adding -lshcore.


The code is pretty long and is called from Java (JNI), so I can't just show it.

@TechoftheAbsence Why show me the command without -lshcore? Where did you add it, to the right of .cpp? It has no effect when to the left of .cpp, for example. "so I can't just show it" Then prepare a [mcve]. We need a piece of code and a compiler command that produces the same error as you get.

g++ -c -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" src\main\java\com\azcomplex\com_azcomplex_CHandler.cpp -lshcore - here it is.

@TechoftheAbsence Are you getting undefined reference to SetProcessDpiAwareness, or to some other function?

Of course to SetProcessDpiAwarness, else I would not public code with it in the question.

@TechoftheAbsence Can you reproduce the error on the exact code you have in the question, when you compile it with just g++ file.cpp -lshcore?

I've got pretty interesting result: it works. Moreover, it also works with the original file. The problem actually was in an another command in the .bat file, that has not -lshcore in it.
